# List comprehension for turning a lists of lists of strings into a list of lists of ints and float

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists. The sublists each contain three strings.

```
bins = [['1', '2', '3.5'], ['4', '5', '6.0']]
```

I need to convert this into a lists of lists where each sublist consists of two integers and a float. I was thinking of a list comprehension along the lines of:

```
[ [int(start), int(stop), float(value)] for bn in bins for [start, stop, value] in bn]
```

Comment: sure... your idea looks like it would work ... whats the question here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close:

```
[[int(start), int(stop), float(value)] for start, stop, value in bins]
```

You don't need the `bn` variable to hold each bin or a loop to iterate through its contents; each bin can be unpacked directly into the three variables.

Comment: Doh! So obvious in retrospect :-S

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `map`

```
>>> bins = [['1', '2', '3.5'], ['4', '5', '6.0']]
>>> map(lambda x: [int(x[0]), int(x[1]), float(x[2])], bins)
[[1, 2, 3.5], [4, 5, 6.0]]
```